# How to create and traverse decision tree in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, decision-tree, diagram

I am trying to create a Tree in python that looks like this diagram:

[image: Diagram]

How do I write code in Python to create this tree and find a given "answer" or leaf node, given gender and color.

For example:

```
Input: { Gender : "Female", Color : "Green" }

Output: "Message 5"
```

I am going to add more levels and nodes, so I trying to create a tree representation rather than a bunch of "if" statements, since that could be messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the tree in a `dict` structure, e.g.:

```
tree = {'Male': {'Red': 'Message 1', 'Green': 'Message 2', 'Blue': 'Message 3'}, 
        'Female': {'Red': 'Message 4', 'Green': 'Message 5', 'Blue': 'Message 6'}}
```

Then traversing this tree is nothing more than key lookups, e.g.:

```
In []:
i = {'Gender' : "Female", 'Color' : "Green" }
tree[i['Gender']][i['Color']]


Out[]:
"Message 5"
```